# strict convexity attains minimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, convexity-inequality

exercise:

Let $f$ be a strictly convex function defined in an interval $A$.
Suppose that there exist distinct points $a$ and $b$ in $A$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$
Show that $f$ attains a minimum.

If $f$ continuous in the closed interval $[a,b]$ then by extreme value theorem it attains it's minimum. It is a trivial case.

By the previous theorems we know that strict convex functions is continuous in an open interval $(a,b)$
and by definition of convexity $f(t a+(1-t) b)<t f(a)+(1-t) f(b)$ we have $f(a)=f(b)>f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$

I thought a lot considering theese facts but I couldn't figure out. Could anyone help me, please.

Comment: You probably need to assume that $a,b$ are in the interior of the interval.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat the book claims so. I copied the exercise as it is. May be somewhere before $a$ and $b$ considered as interior points which I missed. or may be it is a blunder from author (less probably). I am not a native english speaker may be I missed some points.

Comment: But if $a$ and $b$ are interior points why we need $f(a)=f(b)$???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true, as stated. Take, for example, the function
$$f : [0, 1] \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } 0 < x \le 1 \\1 & \text{if }x = 0.\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is a strictly convex function, satisfying $f(0) = f(1)$, with an infimum of $0$ that is not achieved.

I don't believe this can be done without some assumption of continuity at the endpoints, which would put you back in the "trivial" case.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Theo Bendit but if $a$ and $b$ are interior points why we need $f(a)=f(b)$??? because extreme value theorem doesn't need this equality. I made copy paste this exercise from the book. It is unbelievable such blunder from professor))

Comment: It’s possible that they wanted you to show it achieved a minimum somewhere in $(a,b)$? If $a, b \in \operatorname{int} A$ satisfy $a <b$, then this conclusion is true. But, I wouldn’t waste any more headspace on trying to fix this problem. It’s broken, the correct solution is in my answer, and you already have the tools to solve similar, not-so-broken questions.

Comment: Thanks again Theo Bendit.  I think so too